# HTML.TextBoxFor is being pre populated with model name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an HTML.TextBoxFor that is being pre populated with System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

i have tried adding a null attribute and and empty "" but that just throws an error. How can i have it load and empty textbox.

```
@foreach (var item in pendingReg.PaymentOptions.RegistrationPaymentTypes)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.PendingRegistrations.Cart[i].PaymentOptions.PaymentTypes, item.RegistrationTypePaymentTypeID, new { data_val = item.PaymentTypeID })
    <span>@item.PaymentName</span>
    <br />
    if (item.PaymentTypeID == 4)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.PendingRegistrations.Cart[i].PaymentOptions.PurchaseOrders, null, new { @class = "textboxClass", @value=""})

    }
}
```

Comment: Is your property(`PurchaseOrders`) a collection type ? How are you expecting a collection to be rendered with a textbox ?

Comment: thank you for the response, it helped me figured it out! i had purchase orders created as a List of string... when it shouldve just been a public int string